# Programmatically Suppressing Graphs in Crystal Reports

Tags: graph, crystal-reports, formula

I'm using Crystal Reports to create some graphs. I'm linking students in a report showing a graph of results for each subject

Student
Ian  Smoth  UREL5  U  TU

Course
UREL5  5  9  23  33  23  6  1
LREL5  10  13  23  27  20  7

Dependent on whether the the course is an Upper or Lower course I want to give them a different graph, as the axis change.  You can see that LREL5 doesn't have the same number of fields.

Is there a way in Crystal Reports to suppress the display of a graph if certain criteria is met?

I'm looking to do the following in the 'Formula Workshop':

```
if {All_Students_txt.Qual Level} = "U" then
   suppress LowerGraph
else
   suppress UpperGraph
```

Alternatively I could mess about with dynamically updating the graph on each record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to create a separate section for each graph (right click the section and choose Insert Section Below), then suppress the appropriate section.  This approach gives you more flexibility.

The suppression formula for the 'upper' section would be:

```
{All_Students_txt.Qual Level} <> "U"
```

The suppression formula for the 'lower' section would be:

```
{All_Students_txt.Qual Level} = "U"
```